# More robust choice for filesystem

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, filesystems, filesystem-corruption

I have to format a new external HD, 1 TB. I want to have an independent partition of ~300 GB which should be very robust against damage (last time I lost the entire HD since it fall down).

Of course I do backup, ... but here I can sacrifice performance for robustness. I use it only with linux. Which filesystem should I choose, which configurations?

Comment: Regardless of the file-system chosen, if you drop a HDD it can still be damaged.

Comment: SSDs are much mere robust than HDDs, especially when they fall or get knocked. The file system has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I agree, but maybe there are fs better than other. For example the dropped hd had a btrfs and I was able to recover many files. Is this true for all the fs? Are there fs easier to recover from physical damage, ...?

Comment: Why, ZFS, of course. ;) It’s the final word in filesystems, after all.

Answer (score 1):

You've actually already found the answer -- `btrfs` was designed from ground up to sustain as much damage as a design can handle (e.g. physical damage is beyond any logical design can handle).

To read more on `btrfs`, check out:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Btrfs
https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ubuntu_support
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1uY5MLsoQ-lzfIsVcEwZjaXmQLyuKwlAV87KULXGQaQw/edit?usp=sharing